# Angular 7 application as Chat Plugin in another website

Tags: angular, plugins, widget

I have a chat application which is built in angular 7, now i want to use it as chat widget/plugin in another website.

Is it possible?

Comment: Maybe it what do you need: https://angular.io/guide/elements

Comment: What if the other website is non-angular application?

Comment: Angular elements pack your app into native WebComponent, and you may use it as encapsulated module. So no metter, host website use angular, react or vanillaJS.

Comment: If you understand russian I can send you good article about it.